# Confusion about axiomatic FOL

Tags: logic

I’m quite confused by axiomatic approaches to FOL. I was taught FOL by means of Fitch-style natural deduction. In these kinds of systems, rules like Existential Elimination (EE) and Universal Introduction (UI) require a bit of care, but they’re not too difficult. In order to preserve generality for UI, one may infer ∀xFx from Fa just in case ‘a’ is an arbitrary name. This means that ‘a’ does not occur in any assumption or hypothesis. An assumption is a premise that does not get discharged, and a hypothesis is a premise that must eventually be discharged. For EE, it’s quite similar. Note that the system that I’ve  learned and that I’m referencing does not sanction any use of free variables.

Now, in axiomatic treatments of FOL, this all goes haywire (from my perspective). As I understand it, axiomatic FOL has both bound and free variables, constants, and terms. I have almost no idea how to differentiate these concepts in axiomatic FOL, and the brief “x must not be free in phi” or “y must be free for psi” snippets on Wikipedia and in journal articles don’t cut it. I can tell whether or not a variable is free or bound in a given formula, but that’s about it.

My main concern is the use of “φ->∀xφ when x is not free in φ” as an axiom schema. Why can’t I just take the contrapositive, do hypothetical syllogism, and say “if not everything is  φ, then everything is not φ” since ‘x’ is still not free in φ.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your actual question is. Right now this reads more like a complaint than a question. Are you asking for an explanation of the formula you list?

Comment: I’ve edited my final paragraph to make my question clearer.

Comment: Your example with quantifier axiom is not clear... Also UI of Natural Deduction has the proviso that you cannot introduce the quantifier if x is free in an assumption.

Comment: Having said that, axioms are chosen to be valid formula that are suitable for a sound anc complete proof system. One of the solutioni is simply to use all ND rules in "axiom form".

Comment: Note that $\varphi \leftrightarrow \forall x \varphi$ (when $x$ is not free in $\varphi$) is also valid, since we've already forced the truth value of $\varphi$ to be completely independent of $x$. Please see [this guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question?cb=1) for advice on asking a good question. I recommend you focus on one axiomatic presentation of FOL specifically and find one aspect of it that's confusing and make that the sole focus of the question, and quote the whole presentation of FOL in the question.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA here’s where my confusion comes from. Tell me where I’m wrong. 

1. φ->∀xφ (x not free in φ).  

2. ~∀xφ->~φ (transposition)
3. ~φ->∀x~φ (x not free in φ)

4.~∀xφ-> ∀x~φ (Hyp. Syll.)

Comment: @Pdubya_24 That deduction is correct... what's wrong with 4? It seems perfectly valid to me (when $x$ is not free in $\varphi$, of course).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen It’s not a deduction, but it is a proof. I made no assumptions.

Comment: @Pdubya_24 Ok... so your *proof* is correct. What's your point?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I think his point is that the proof *seems* to lead to a problematic conclusion, that being $\lnot \forall x \phi \to \forall x \lnot \phi$.

Comment: @NicolinoWill Thus my initial question of why that conclusion is problematic. (The funny thing here is that already  $\varphi \to \forall x \varphi$ clearly invalid, if not for the crucial assumption that $x$ is not free in $\varphi$. There's no need to twist it around.)

Comment: @Pdubya_24 - see spaceisdarkgreen's comments. If $x$ is not free in $\varphi$ we have something like $(0 <1) \to \forall x (0 <1)$. The formula is satisfied in the usual arithmetical interpretation.

Answer (score 4):

If the sentence "it is not the case that for every squirrel $x$, the mafia killed JFK" is true, that must be because "the mafia killed JFK" is false, i.e. the "for every squirrel $x$" clause is rendered completely irrelevant by the fact that "$x$" does not appear in the predicate.

Thus, by similar reasoning, "for every squirrel $x$, the mafia didn't kill JFK" is also true, since, as we just established under our assumption, "the mafia didn't kill JFK" is true.

So by the conditional proof of the previous two paragraphs, the implication "if it is not the case that for every squirrel $x$, the mafia killed JFK, then for every squirrel $x$, the mafia didn't kill JFK" is true.

So, in other words, the thing you think is a not valid (presumably because bears some resemblance to a well-known fallacy) is in fact valid **under the assumption that $x$ is not free in $\varphi.$**

There was really no reason to pass to the form $\lnot\forall x\varphi \to \forall x\lnot \varphi,$ as already, $\varphi \to \forall x \varphi$ is blatantly invalid without the side condition that $x$ is not free in $\varphi,$ whereas with the side condition it becomes valid for the same reason as before (though perhaps it is a bit simpler in this context).

Comment: My real issue is that this is a proof; not merely a derivation. That means that every line in the proof is an unconditional tautology. Clearly, the conclusion is not valid unless it’s been proven that φ holds for an arbitrary term/constant/variable/name/whatever. I guess I don’t know how this would work without the Greek. Fa->∀xFx is invalid, and since I’ve never worked with free variables, I have no idea how to tell whether Fy->∀xFx is also invalid by just looking at it.

Comment: @Pdubya_24 There is no material difference between free variables and constants in assessing the unconditional validity of formulas. So, $Fy\to \forall x Fx$ is invalid. But how is that relevant? It's not even of the form $\varphi \to \forall x \varphi.$ On the other hand, $Fy\to \forall x Fy$ is of that form, and valid, since $x$ doesn't occur freely in $Fy$.

Comment: I’m not following. Fy->∀xFy isn’t even a wff because there is no variable ‘x’ under the scope of the universal quantifier.

Comment: @Pdubya_24 Is this a rule for wffs in your system? I've never encountered that rule to my recollection, and in any event, it is "standard" that a quantifier scope doesn't need to include any instances of the variable to be well-formed. Moreover, I'm extra skeptical in the present context, since if that were the case, $\varphi \to \forall x \varphi$ would never be well-formed under the side condition. So something's off somewhere. This underscores Greg's comment above, that if you have a question about a certain system, you should specify the system.

Comment: It has always been my understanding that “∀xφ” is a shorthand for something like ∀x(Fx v Gx), and that nullary predicates/propositional constants can’t be under the scope of a quantifier, unless there is some other formula under the scope of the same quantifier in which the variable bound by the quantifier appears.

Comment: Please refer to section 6.2 in the following for the FOL formation rules I learned. https://www.csus.edu/indiv/d/dowdenb/160/Nolt%20Logics%202.pdf

Comment: @Pdubya_24 That's presumably a reference to where you learned natural deduction... not to a system where you saw this axiom. You are correct that the formation rules here prohibit vacuous quantification here... indeed they prohibit free variables entirely. This is not the usual way of doing things, even in a natural deduction context, in my experience. I would bet that whatever axiomatic system you are looking at will admit something like $\forall x Fy$ as well-formed.

Comment: Can you provide a reference?

Comment: To what? To first order logic formation rules that allow vacuous quantification? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Formation_rules . And here's a compatible Hilbert-style system https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system#Logical_axioms

Comment: @Pdubya_24 Also, a somewhat random sample of standard general logic / FOL textbooks that allow vacuous quantification (I didn't check if these all present Hilbert systems... some certainly do. On the other end, Negri/Von Plato does ND/Sequents with formation rules allowing vac quantification.): Hedman, Leary and Kristianson, Enderton, Mendelson, Smullyan, Shoenfield.

Comment: Even though it’s odd to me, I’m not too worried about vacuous quantification. I don’t understand how Fy->∀xFx doesn’t fit the form of the axiom schema as I don’t know what a valid instance of the axiom looks like without vacuous quantification.

Comment: @Pdubya_24 The schema is $\varphi \to \forall x \varphi,$ which means you can substitute some formula (obeying the side condition) for $\varphi$ to get an axiom. $Fy$ and $Fx$ are different formulas, so $Fy\to \forall x F x$ isn't an instance of this. On the other hand $Fx\to \forall x Fx$ is an appropriate substitution of $Fx$ for $\varphi$, but not an instance of the schema since $Fx$ has $x$ free so doesn't obey the side condition. Whereas, $Fy \to \forall x Fy$ is both a correct substitution and obeys the side condition, so it is an instance of the schema.

Comment: Can you give an example that doesn’t use vacuous quantification since it is unnecessary for FOL and is thus not a pertinent example for how to implement this axiom in proofs correctly?

Comment: @Pdubya_24 That’s impossible. Nothing of the form $\varphi\to\forall x\varphi$ is well-formed when $x$ is not free in $\varphi$ if vacuous quantification is not well-formed.

Comment: @Pdubya_24 In other words, this axiom scheme makes no sense in that context. I think in such a context it is just not needed and can be dropped without sacrificing completeness, but I haven't really thought it through... Hilbert systems are finicky.